# Type definition in parentheses

Tags: c++, c, definition, parentheses

I compiled these codes in MSVC:

```
int a=sizeof(struct{char c;});
```

and

```
int b=((struct{char c;} *)0,0);
```

and

```
printf("%p",(struct{char c;} *)0);
```

As C codes, they can pass compiling, with a warning (*warning c4116: unnamed type definition in parentheses*. If you give a name, it's "*warning c4115: "Whatever" : named type definition in parentheses*");
As C++ codes, they are compiled with a bunch of errors.

My questions are:
1. In C, are type definitions in parentheses valid? Why do I get that warning?
2. In C++, are type definitions in parentheses valid?

**EDIT :**
3. Why?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is invalid in C++ and possibly valid in C (or maybe just an extension).

Comment: What is the point of this question? Where would this be useful?

Comment: @user1920482, That's not a good test at all. Consider `int &r = 5;`, which can compile with MSVC, and is known as an evil compiler extension. Or consider VLAs, which are, as of C++11, still not standard, but many people use them.

Comment: @user1920482, That was a quick example. I didn't test it and my version of MSVC might have the whole thing fixed, but take a look at [these questions](https://www.google.ca/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+non-const+reference+from+temporary&rlz=1C1CHFX_enCA561CA561&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+non-const+reference+from+temporary&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.16430j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Among the examples, R4F is nice enough to give a warning: http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/XDfp

Comment: @chris: comment deleted.

Comment: @RedX, possible use is, #define ALIGN_OF(T) ((size_t)(&(((struct{char _; T t;}*)0)->t)))

Comment: @zwhconst, Why would you need a macro for that?

Comment: @RedX, to get alignment of types, as parameters to memory allocation routine, and __alignof is buggy. There's maybe other use, I can't think of one though.

Answer (score 5):

In C, `sizeof` can be applied to any *type-name* that is not an incomplete type (6.5.3.4p1); a *struct-or-union-specifier* that contains a struct declaration list (6.7.2.1p1) is a *type-specifier* and thus a *type-name*.  MSVC's warning is there for two reasons: first, because some older compilers (or a C++ compiler used as a C compiler) might not support this usage, and second, because it's unusual and might not be what you intended.

In C++, `sizeof` can be applied to a *type-id*; a *class-specifier* is a *type-specifier* and thus a *type-id*, but a class specifier that defines a class (or an enum specifier that defines an enumeration) can only appear in a class declaration or a `using` declaration (7.1.6p3).  This is probably because C++ classes can have linkage and allowing them to appear in general expressions (not just definitions) would complicate this.

Answer (score 3):

In C:

```
sizeof(struct{char c;})
```

and

```
sizeof((struct{char c;} *)0,0)
```

are both valid expressions. An implementation is free to issue an additional informational diagnostic messages for valid C code.

Comment: @V-X it is an expression formed with the C comma operator

Comment: @V-X, The comma operator has the lowest precedence, so it's much more than 0,0, but it's effectively just `0` in this case, save the optional diagnostics on the first part.

Comment: This helps. But in C++? What clauses make it valid/invalid in the standard?

Comment: @zwhconst, 7.1.6 [dcl.type], paragraph 3: A *type-specifier-seq* shall not define a class or enumeration unless it appears in the *type-id* of an *alias-declaration*.

Comment: @zwhconst in C it is valid because it follows the syntax for C structure declarations, where the tag identifier is optional *(C99, 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers, Syntax)*

Comment: I know, but what should that mean sizeof(0)?

Comment: @V-X `0` literal is a value of type `int`: `sizeof 0` is therefore equivalent to `sizeof (int)`